# How to pass Link id between pages in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, mern

I'm making an application using the MERN stack where I have different chats that a user is a part of and the user can click on one of the chat links to go to that chat page. I don't want to create a page for each chat, so instead, what I'm doing is I use the id of the chat (I have a map call where I assign an id to each Link that corresponds to a chat) to get the chat, and then return the display the chat data to the screen. However, I need to know which chat the user clicked on to make this work. Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: Please review [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt, details on what is or isn't working, debugging details, and actual and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass id of every item to Link in Router:

```
<Route path=`link/${chatID}` component = {ChatComponent}/>
```

Comment: Almost got it, but `\`/link/${chatID}\`` would be generated for the `Link`. The `Route` would/could be `<Route path="/link/:chatId" component={ChatComponent} />`.